# Add the child to the nested field of the parent document in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to create a parent child relationship in document in elastic search. But the child document should reference the nested field value see below.

```
PUT DemoIndex/_doc/1
{
   "Name":"XYX",
   "ClassGrads":[
        {"I":"A"},
        {"II","A"},
        {"III","A"},
        {"IV","A"},
        {"V","A"},
   ]
 }
```

So I want to map the child document with the item of ClassGrads and keep DemoIndex as parent document.

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public List<DemoClass> Field3 { get; set; }

}

public class DemoClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

So child document will be mapped to the Id of the demo class. This is the problem statement

Based on the POCO I have create the index as below.

```
   var indexResponse = elasticClient.CreateIndex("parentindex", s => s
                             .Index<Parent>()
                                 .Mappings(ms => ms
                                   .Map<Parent>(m => m
                                        .RoutingField(r => r.Required())
                                            .AutoMap<Parent>()
                                            .AutoMap<ChildClass>()
                                                .Properties(prop => prop
                                                    .Join(j => j
                                                        .Name(p => p.Field3 .FirstOrDefault().Id)
                                                        .Relations(r => r
                                                            .Join<Parent, ChildClass>()
                                                        )
                                                    )
                                                 )
                                    )   
                                )
                            );
```

Is there is anything I am missing here ?
Because I got the index creation response as valid but when I am going to see the mappings it says index not created.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/parent-child-relationships.html, and edit your question if you get stuck

Comment: @RussCam Can you see the question again.

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation? What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @RussCam Can you see the question again

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you using? Please take a look at the documentation as you are missing key elements for this to work correctly: (1) both Parent and Child types should share a common base type and (2) there must be a `JoinField` on the common base type that holds the data for how children relate to parents. This is true for Elasticsearch 6.x and onwards

Comment: @RussCam Can I have same example in curl reference.

Comment: Take a look at the `join` datatype docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html.